# Protractor + Hybrid Angular 1+2 Application = Fail

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, angular, end-to-end

Protractor works well on Angular 1 but after upgrading my app to an hybrid Angular 1+2 I get this error:

> Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page:
>   "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.9/ng/test"

*It seems a common error when you don't have a ng-app tag `<div ng-app=myAppManager">` in your Angular 1 app and can be easily fixed wiyh `rootElement : 'html'` in your protractor config file but it doesn't seem to change anything on hybrid app.*

I tried `rootElement : 'html'` or even `useAllAngular2AppRoots: true`.

**I suspect the problem comes from the asynchronous loading of the hybrid angular (from the [upgrade](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/upgrade.html) doc):**

> One notable difference between angular.bootstrap and
>   upgradeAdapter.bootstrap is that the latter works asynchronously. This
>   means that we cannot assume that the application has been instantiated
>   immediately after the bootstrap call returns.

my config file:

```
exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine2',
    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
    specs: ['protractor.js'],
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 50000,
    },
    allScriptsTimeout: 50000,//seb
    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'chromeOptions': {
            'prefs': {
                'profile.managed_default_content_settings.notifications':2
            }
        }
    },
    rootElement : 'html',
    // useAllAngular2AppRoots: true,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        realtimeFailure: true
    },
    onPrepare: function() {
      var failFast = require('jasmine-fail-fast');
      jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(failFast.init());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protractor team has fixed with this:

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7603

**Edit: I haven't tested it yet**

**Edit 2: Doesn't seem to work, I went back to angularJs (version 1)**

**Edit 3: I moved to React**

Comment: From what I'm seeing this still is not working. My angular pages fail with:

Failed: Error while waiting for Protractor to sync with the page: "[ng:test] no injector found for element argument to getTestability

I'm using RC5 and have set ng12Hybrid: true in my protractor config.

Comment: has this been fixed?

Comment: @Sebastien Horin a better choise would have been to switch from protractor to cypress..

Comment: @scipper I use Cypress with React, Angular killed himself with this lack of support. They are late now.